# Is the function $g$ from the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $g(S) =$ sum of elements of $S$ onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $F$ be the set of all finite subsets of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Define a function $g: F \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $g(S) =$ the sum of the integers in $S$ for any element $S \in F$. Determine if the function $g$ is onto or not. Support your answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i dont know how to go about solving this question

Comment: Can you explain what it means to say $g$ is onto?

Comment: for g to be onto for element in z there has to be be two or more elements matching with set f

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648666/89922) earlier from another Jenna?

Comment: can You help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you (via another account, on another post) asked in the comments for "guidance in how to approach solving the problem". Here is the best guidance I can give.

---

**The first step to answering any question is to make sure you understand what the question is asking.** That's just because if you don't understand the question, it'll be very hard to answer it correctly!

This problem asks you to

> Determine if the function $g$ is onto or not.

So: do you understand what this is asking? More specifically: do you know what the function $g$ is? Do you know what it means for a function to be onto?

If yes, challenge yourself on this. Could you explain to someone else what it means for a function to be onto? Could you explain to someone else exactly what $g$ is?

This is genuinely the most important step. You **must** confirm to yourself that you understand the question before you can continue. To reiterate: do not proceed until you understand the question!

---

**Once you know what the question is asking, you need to ask yourself "what would constitute a valid answer"?**

This questions asks you to

> Determine if the function $g$ is onto or not. Support your answer.

So, we need to

1. Give a yes or no answer: is $g$ onto or not?
2. Give a *proof* (either that $g$ is onto or that $g$ is not onto).

We know how to give a yes or no answer: we just say "yes" or "no"!

The harder part is the proof. What would it mean to prove that $g$ is onto? In other words, if someone showed you a proof they wrote that $g$ is onto, how could you tell if it is correct?

Likewise, what would it mean to prove that $g$ is not onto? If someone showed you a proof they wrote that $g$ is not onto, how could you tell if it is correct?

This step is also essential! If you don't know what it would mean to prove that $g$ is or is not onto, it will be very hard to write a valid proof of such a fact.

---

If you have those two steps down:

1. understanding what the question is asking,
2. understanding what an answer will entail

the rest will come much more easily. :)